# Create Neo4j DBMS user that has access to a subset of databases

Tags: neo4j

I would like to create a user for a Neo4j Enterprise instance that has full access to three of the databases in that instance.

Here is what I tried:

- create new user
- create a new role
- add the role to the new user
- create privileges for the role for each of the three databases following the description here (I assumed `architect` is a reasonable role): https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/access-control/built-in-roles/#access-control-built-in-roles-architect

Here are the Cypher commands:

```
CREATE USER test
    SET PASSWORD "testMe"

CREATE OR REPLACE ROLE testdev;

GRANT ROLE testdev TO test;

GRANT ACCESS ON DATABASE sampledb TO testdev;
GRANT MATCH {sampledb} ON GRAPH sampledb TO testdev;
GRANT WRITE ON GRAPH sampledb TO testdev;
GRANT NAME MANAGEMENT ON DATABASE sampledb TO testdev;
GRANT SHOW CONSTRAINT ON DATABASE sampledb TO testdev;
GRANT CONSTRAINT MANAGEMENT ON DATABASE sampledb TO testdev;
GRANT SHOW INDEX ON DATABASE sampledb TO testdev;
GRANT INDEX MANAGEMENT ON DATABASE sampledb TO testdev;
```

When I log in a s the new user I see an empty graph and none of the three databases. I do not see a database selection dropdown.

How can I create a new user that has full access to three specific databases? Can I copy an existing role and limit it to those databases?

Comment: That should work pretty much out of the box with the steps you described, what is the output of the `SHOW USER PRIVILEGES` command when logged in with your new user ?